# Bold fonts in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a practice to do something like this
[H&M lookalike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ewP9.jpg). But the typography seem to not look the same, both in or out of the image. This is my full code

https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-night-b499r

I have tried this in my css

```css
body {
  background-color: #faf9f8;
  font-family: "Didact Gothic", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar div {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.ontop-image {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

But it doesn't do the job.

So if anyone could tell me why the bold font doesn't look correct, that would be great.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I believe there are some extra custom CSS styles that they've added to the font. Like the spacing of letters and the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't rendering how you think it would be as the font you're loading doesn't have a bold typography style. So its given an automatic bold style, which never really looks that great.

You can see on Google Fonts, the only format they have available is regular:
[image]

I suggest you look for a similar font with more formats, for example [Nunito](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito?selection.family=Nunito) looks very similar and has plenty of font weights.

[image]